# How do I stop Flash video being squashed and broken?

Tags: flash

I recently installed Lubuntu but I have a problem with Adobe Flash Player. I always see something that looks like this when I open a video:

[image]
<sub>(source: [hostingpics.net](https://img11.hostingpics.net/pics/699391201308202200501280x1024scrot.png))</sub>

The video is small, grainy, and is green and purple.

I tried to reinstall Flash and to test it in multiple browsers without success.
I installed an older version of Flash but no result.

```
[0300]: Intel Corporation 82865G Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:2572] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company D530 sff(dc578av) [103c:12bc]
    Kernel driver in use: i915
```

Comment: Cannot find the intel driver installer. It is not under the menu. How can I locate it? Thanx

Comment: @watjilpa It would have been better if you asked this question separately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to be a problem on some computers with Intel graphics cards and Lubuntu. Only follow this if you're using an Intel graphics card.

I had the same exact problem with my kids laptop running Lubuntu 13.04.  I installed, and re-installed flash, tried an older version of flash, and other things, and nothing seems to work.  All I had to do was to download and install the latest graphics driver.  In my case it wan an Intel built in graphics adapter.

Note: I have Lubuntu install updates, and other restricted during installation, and I didn't have to do anything with installing flash.

### Only Intel

[Download this driver from Intel](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads?keys=&download_type=11&download_version=All). Go for the latest version but make sure that you get the right architecture (32 vs 64 bit). You can check this in a terminal by running `uname -i`. If it says x86_64, you want the 64 bit version, otherwise assume you need the 32 bit version.

Then to install it, just press <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, navigate to the Downloads folder, and run the command(s) below:

```
sudo dpkg -i <file_name>.deb
```

Once installed, go under the menu, and click on the Intel driver installer.  I believe it under the accessories menu, but I'm not sure, just look for it.  Once it download the needed files, reboot the system, and see.

Comment: I have the newest drivers... But can you give me more information?

Comment: What graphics adapter do you have?  Have you installed Lubunutu Restricted Extras?

Comment: A VGA one, I have VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 82865G Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:2572] (rev 02)
 Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company D530 sff(dc578av) [103c:12bc]
 Kernel driver in use: i915

Comment: look at the added info in the answer.

Comment: @Mitch, your solution helped [someone else](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2169586&p=12767780#post12767780) too!

Answer (score 0):

Try this from your terminal, first remove old unnecessary package :

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge adobe-flashplugin flashplugin* nspluginwrapper
```

Reinstall flash :

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall adobe-flashplugin
```

Comment: Do you have made a mistake when you wrote 'adobe-flashplugin' ? Because I get this message: 'Package adobe-flashplugin is not available, but is referred to by another package.'
Thank you.

Comment: @حكيمالفيلسوفالضائع Enable the Canonical Partner repository in the software sources settings from within the software centre.

Comment: Even if I do it, it doesn't find it... I enabled all the repositories.