# Flash video appears malformed. How do I fix this?

Tags: firefox, flash, chromium

I wiped my computer a while ago and I re installed a new version of Ubuntu, I believe I was on 11.10 now 12.04. Downloaded the Flash player as usual from the Software Center.

[image]

This is what I get when I try to go to a Youtube video (The size of the screen cap is how large the video *should* be.) When I encountered this, I looked through and found the extra Flash add on that Firefox said it needed being Gnash SWF Viewer, that was a waist, no change.

Downloaded Chromium, same thing happened. Re-installed the Flash player, nothing. I'm stumped frankly, can't find anything around with an answer for this so far, maybe I'm looking for it in a wrong way?

Comment: Take a look at my answer [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/335124/flash-player-a-big-bug), see if it helps.

Comment: Looked around on Google and I couldn't find anything for Ubuntu 12.04. Thank you though.

Comment: What is your graphics adapter?

Comment: I'll be honest, no clue. I've had Ubuntu for a while but I am yet to get in to much of it at all. Just simple things. How would I check? (Sorry for being such a noob X.X)

Comment: Well, still no luck with finding anything, I downloaded some new packages that made my Youtube able to be watched, but my chat is still screwed up. Any more ideas?