# Graphics problem with Lubuntu 13.10 on AMILO Pro v2020

Tags: 13.10, firefox, lubuntu, google-chrome, flash

I installed Lubuntu 12.04 and upgraded to 13.10. I noticed that in both Chrome and Firefox Flash causes some very weird artifacts and behaves strangely. Also I am getting EDID checksum error on boot. The machine I am using is Fujitsu Siemens AMILO Pro v2020, using Intel® 82852/82855 GM integrated graphics. When I had Ubuntu 12.04 installed, Flash worked flawlesly.

Here's the output of `lspci -v`:

```
...
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 82852/855GM Integrated Graphics Device (rev 02) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
Subsystem: Fujitsu Technology Solutions Device 106a
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
Memory at d8000000 (32-bit, prefetchable) [size=128M]
Memory at e0380000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=512K]
I/O ports at ec00 [size=8]
Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: i915

00:02.1 Display controller: Intel Corporation 82852/855GM Integrated Graphics Device (rev 02)
Subsystem: Fujitsu Technology Solutions Device 106a
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
Memory at d0000000 (32-bit, prefetchable) [size=128M]
Memory at e0300000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=512K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
...
```

[Here](https://www.mediafire.com/?da9jdm8xz7dd7wb) is kern.log for the EDID checksum errors and [here](http://i.cubeupload.com/rlUlMr.png) is a screenshot showing an example of the behavior of Flash with a Youtube video (and an advert next to it). As I said, when I had Ubuntu 12.04 installed Flash didn't behave like this. Any ideas for fixing this?

Comment: See if this http://askubuntu.com/questions/335124/how-do-i-stop-flash-video-being-squashed-and-broken/335342#335342, helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/335124/how-do-i-stop-flash-video-being-squashed-and-broken/335342#335342) thread Mitch mentioned, and followed the instructions in the answer. I succesfully installed the Intel drivers, but Flash worked correctly only for one time in a Youtube video, then the weird behavior started again.

I thought about re-installing the Intel driver, and deleted **xserver-xorg-video-intel** package, thinking it's the correct package, and rebooted. Apparently it wasn't the one installed by the Intel installer, but removing the X.Org X server-drivers fixed my problem, and Flash behaves correctly now!