# Video colors wrong 12.04 LTS using VLC or Movie Player

Tags: 12.04, video, vlc

Does anyone have a fix for misrepresented video colors?

Have searched askubuntu.com, have not found a solution that works.

12.04 LTS displays video colors incorrectly using VLC or Movie Player. Also
when viewing videos on youtube, colors are wrong and frame is compressed horizontally. 
Have installed Flashplayer plugin from Ubuntu Software Center, no change, apparently it's not a browser problem.
Problem occurs in Firefox or Chromium, or viewing videos offline. 
Everything else (pictures, thumbnails, etc.) shows correct colors, only videos are effected.

When attempting to view a video in VLC the screen goes black as the cursor crosses in or out of the frame.

I have installed xubuntu-restricted-extras package" from Ububtu Software Center, and Adobe flash plugin.

[image: Screenshot]

UPDATE: Installed "YouTube ALL HTML5 2.1.1" per advice on Ubuntuforums.org, chose the option to disable Flash on Youtube, that cleared up the online video problem. 
Now I need to figure out how to fix the problem when using the offline viewers.

UPDATE: Found that the colors while viewing offline were not negative, just too strong giving that "neon" look. Adjusted saturation, etc., and got close to "normal". Hard to do with VLC, every time I move the mouse, the screen goes black. Similar with Movie Player but I'll figure it out. Probably end up uninstalling VLC as it seems to be a lot of trouble to adjust. Might try some other viewers.

Cancel red alert!

UPDATE: Also found that moving or resizing the image window in Movie Player can bring the image back (make the black go away).

Comment: You could always post an image to imgur and link it. Are you saying that all colours are wrong? Perhaps you need to calibrate your screen? I'm not sure about the aspect ratio and black screen though. (Also, you can take a screenshot without using the mouse with shutter.)

Comment: Everything else (pictures, etc.) shows correct colors, only videos are effected. I have google pics, might try that to post a screenshot, thanks.

Comment: That is so strange. It might be worth uploading a screenshot (and short video) up somewhere, so we can see if it looks the same on our computers. Or just post a youtube link and the relevant screenshot.

Comment: Thanks Sparhawk, just tried to post a pic by link, got the same message. Will try again in a minute.

Comment: Okay, I edited your post to put the screenshot inline. Sorry, can't really help with an answer though. Good luck…

Comment: Oops, hope I didn't edit that out! Also got a message, reputation 10 required to post 2 links. I might have deleted yours!

Comment: Nope, it's still there. :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I stop Flash video being squashed and broken?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/335124/how-do-i-stop-flash-video-being-squashed-and-broken)

Comment: Similar problem but different OS and slightly different symptoms.